# which value in ICMP(scapy) is responsible to convey path MTU value

Tags: networking

In scapy ICMP there are several values

```
 type      = dest-unreach
 code      = fragmentation-needed
 chksum    = 0x3c4a
 reserved  = 5
 length    = 20
 nexthopmtu= 1300
```

I crafted a packet that looks like Ether/IP/ICMP/IP/UDP
Here the IP/UDP is the packet that will cause the error. My target VM will always send this packet. So when I send the ICMP back, it will recognize it.

But I'm not sure which value in ICMP is responsible for path MTU reset. I want to change the path MTU as I wish. From other references, there is a value called 'unused' in ICMP that may do the work. So every time I send the packet, I will set it(unused = 1300). But the target VM  didn't change the MTU as I wish. The target VM's firewall is disabled and I can get the packet in VM using Wireshark. The packet looks perfect to me. I'm wondering what's the problem.

Comment: Did the IP header of the original outgoing UDP packet have the Don't Fragment bit set? Was the packet bigger than 1300? Does the IP stack in the VM's OS do Path MTU Discovery?

Comment: @Spiff Yeah, DF and MF are set to 0 in my target VM. The ICMP and UDP are both below 1300 and I use PING with over 1300 payload to check whether the mtu is set. My target VM has net.ipv4.ip_no_pmtu_disc = 0. So MTU discovery is enabled.